# Python short-circuiting of functions

Tags: python, short-circuiting

I know that Python's short-circuiting behavior works with functions. Is there any reason it wouldn't work when two functions are combined into one? I.e., why does this short-circuit,

```
>>> menu = ['spam']
>>> def test_a(x):
...     return x[0] == 'eggs'  # False.
...
>>> def test_b(x):
...     return x[1] == 'eggs'  # Raises IndexError.
...
>>> test_a(menu) and test_b(menu)
False
```

whereas this doesn't?

```
>>> condition = test_a and test_b
>>> condition(menu)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test_b
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did this:

```
>>> condition = test_a and test_b
```

you incorrectly expected to get a new function that returns the result `test_a(x) and test_b(x)`. You actually got the [evaluation of a Boolean expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

> `x and y`: if *x* is false, then *x*, else *y*

Since the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of both `test_a` and `test_b` is `True`, `condition` is set to `test_b`. This is why `condition(menu)` gives the same result as `test_b(menu)`.

To achieve the expected behavior, do:

```
>>> def condition(x):
...     return test_a(x) and test_b(x)
...
```